# Lotus Notes 5.1 Extract VIEW data into CSV File and FTP it to Unix Server

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

Is it possible to write agent in Lotus notes R5 version to extract all data from one VIEW , put it into CSV and Ftp it to Unix server.

Comment: Yes. Create the CSV file with LotusScript and use NotesFTP https://www.socialbizug.org/blogs/articles/entry/notesftp_so_easy_to_use?lang=en / http://www.bananahome.com/ldd/sandbox.nsf/ByApplicationName/9e752a60b6f902c7852568ef006b4ad1?OpenDocument

Comment: Is there any example how to "Create the CSV file with LotusScript " from View like Select * From ViewName and put into CSV

Comment: You could also hire a developer who know the Notes/Domino platform, what you describe is a very simple task. Since it sounds like you have very limited knowledge of Notes, it would probably be much more cost efficient for you to get a competent Notes developer than for you to learn it all from scratch yourself.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I am not notes developer , just checking if option feasible with Lotus notes R5 version.

Comment: In that case, the answer is 'Yes', it is possible.

Comment: Why not upgrade to R8 or R9? Export to CSV is a standard option there.

Answer (score 0):

As Knut said, you can easily write a CSV exporter in Lotusscript. If you have ever worked with VB, you should have no problems. 
Also, you don't use select statements to access views. You might want to learn some of the basics about Notes/Domino before you start doing any development, that will help you...

I wrote some code that I posted on my blog a while back, after other Indian developer asked the same question: http://bit.ly/11y09vG
You could also take a look at this: http://bit.ly/H7077T

Comment: Is there any way to have this coding outside of lotus notes. For e.g. using some SQL adapter or POwershell script etc..

Comment: Yes. You should be able to use VBS. However, you need the Notes client installed on the system where you want to run the code (as it need certain DLL files), so why not write it in Lotusscript then? You could hire a competent developer, it's an easy job for anyone who know what they are doing.